# Redirect all requests to index.php using .htaccess

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I am writing my own PHP MVC framework. My web server is installed to /public and i made a directory named myframework. under this directory i have some sub directory and i want to redirect all requests to myframework/public/index.php and also i want to have request url. I made .htaccess file under myframework directory like below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myframework/public/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works for all requests but localhost/myframework/. It does nothing when this request is coming. How can i fix it?

Comment: where have you placed the htaccess file? is it inside public folder? if so then just move it to /myframework/

Comment: No, it is under myframework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

says not to rewrite when the request points to a real directory, which is what `localhost/myframework/` is requesting. Take it out and your rewrite should kick in.