# .htaccess Redirect all url requests to single page with query

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect any url request to my "index.php" page, plus a query string. like this:

if user typed "mydomain.com/foo" in address bar, htaccess redirect it to "index.php" but in php file `$_SERVER[]` variable contain "foo" string

in other word i need any string after "mydomain.com/" save in a variable in "index.php" file.

```
another examples:
mydomain.com/new/bar ----> "new/bar"
mydomain.com/search?color=15 ----> "search?color=15"
```

is it possible with htaccess or must try another way?

Comment: Certainly this is possible. And this question has been answered about 4548264538 times alone here on SO. None of those answers helped you solve this task? _Why not?_ Take a look at the "Related" section on the right side for a start.

Comment: @arkascha Unfortunately I've spend some hours to find right answer from last topics. those are very similar, but none of them do my example.

Comment: Sure, but those similar answers should be enough to solve the task yourself. Take for example that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433092/redirect-all-requests-to-index-php-using-htaccess All you have to do is remove the `q=` and you got your solution. Or you leave away the whole `?q=$1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to rewrite  all requests to the index.php file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

and then in the index.php file you can use the following php code to get the requested uri :

```
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working for me. :) Just I should a little customize it in my local apache server